# Weighted median of a portfolio

Tags: matlab, excel, median, weighted-mean

I need to calculate weighted median return for a portfolio (using MATLAB).  There is information available online: [MATLAB Central/rates&weights](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/97571) and [Excel/note 4+4+4+7+7/5 logic](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/how-do-i-calculate-a-weighted-median.3549384/)

How would you calculate weighted median for following portfolios with given weights and returns?

Much of online help is about returns with frequencies. 
I think the Matlab code in the solution above does not account for ties correctly.

Eg.
A portfolio has 6 investments with the following returns:

```
            A       B     C     D     E     F
weights:    0.1     0.1   0.1   0.2   0.1   0.4
returns:    10%     20%   30%   1%    2%    1%

weighted mean = *easy!*
weighted median = 1%??

            A      B     C      D      E      F     G     H
weights:    0.15   0.1   0.15   0.09   0.01   0.01  0.14  0.35
returns:    0.05%  1%    1%     1%     1%     2%    2%    5%

weighted mean = *easy!*
weighted median = 1.5%?? <or should it be (1+1+1+1+2+2)/6??>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what sense you think it treats ties incorrectly?  The weighted median in the example quite clearly is 1%, because the weights assigned to it are 0.6 out of 1.0, showing that 1% constitutes the bottom 60% of this weighted empirical distribution.

Comment: Please see the updated example.  I have added the (1+1+1+1+2+2)/6 in the query now to highlight my doubt.  Medians are not affected by this but per the second URL, I want to be sure I'm not missing anything.  I haven't used weighted medians before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As detailed in this [answer on the math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50147/is-there-something-called-a-weighted-median), weights in a weighted median are expressed duplicates of the datum. In your top example, replace the weights with their multiples of ten, like so:

```
            A       B     C     D     E     F
weights:    1       1     1     2     1     4
returns:    10%     20%   30%   1%    2%    1%
```

Sort these by return and you have `1 1 1 1 1 1 2 10 20 30`; the median of this pseudo-dataset is the weighted median, in this case the average of the middle two values, i.e. 1%. If you repeat this exercise for the second set, you'll see that the value is 1.5%.

Also note that the weighted-median is the same for any vector of weights proportional to this one. (This is straightforward to prove, but I leave that to you.)

Comment: Can you please check - I get median in second case as 1.5% when done manually using your approach

Comment: You are correct, I must have switched a number or two :)